# Extracting similar image patches captured from 2 different lenses of the same camera

Tags: matlab, opencv, image-processing, camera-calibration

[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlUKg.jpg)

I have 2 images captured from my iPhone 8 plus and each of them have been captured at different zoom levels of the iPhone camera (this implies one image was captured with a 1x zoom and the other at 2x zoom). And now I wanna try and extract an image patch in Picture with 1x zoom corresponding to the zoomed in image i.e. Image with 2x Zoom. How would one go about doing that ?

I understand that SIFT features maybe helpful but is there a way I could use the information about the camera extrinsic and intrinsic matrices to find out the desired region of interest ?

(I'm just looking for hints)

Comment: The camera is kept stationary during the capture of both the inages

Comment: Please add images to help visualising your problem.

Comment: @RahulKedia Sorry about it, Please click on example image now.

Comment: @RahulKedia Just to be clear again I want to find the right image inside the left image